# Fluent NHibernate with ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a web api with Asp.net core and FluentNHibernate however I am getting  the following exception:

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a
>   SessionFactory.

The inner exception is:

> Could not load type System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter from
>   assembly.

I researched this and found asp.net core does not have the Performance counter and I went on to install a package for this. However it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?